# Valid JSON, but "No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: python, json

I have this very short JSON-code in a "utf-8 without BOM"-encoded file:

```
{ "paths": ["A:\\path\\to\\dir"],
  "anotherPath": "os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..')"
}
```

I ensured its validity with different online JSON validators.
But with following Python code...

```
jsonfile = "working\\path\\to\\myProgram.conf"
with open(jsonfile) as conf:
    confContent = json.load(conf)
# doStuff...
```

... I receive this error:

```
No JSON object could be decoded
```

I know that the path is correct, because I read its content successfully at a different place.
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Is it possible to create an example that is reproducible? (It certainly doesn't happen on my machine, so it's very difficult to diagnose). Or at least show the full traceback?

Comment: Look at http://pastebin.com/X2Mh8KSX, which is your exact code, together with some code that writes that exact string as a "utf-8 without BOM"-encoded file beforehand, and it seems to work for me in both 2.7 and 3.3 on Mac and 2.7 on Windows. Does it not work for you? Can you compare the generated `test.json` file to your existing `myProgram.con` file?

Comment: As a side note: Why do you have doubled forward slashes? That's documented to be harmless on POSIX, and happens to be harmless with most APIs on Windows, but it's still an odd thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The comparison to your test.json did the trick. My editor found it to be funny to switch back to ANSI every time I closed the file.
Also the double forward slashes should be double backslashes of course.
Does it make a difference if it is Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @fuchsgeist: Whenever you're dealing with Unicode issues, Python 2 vs. 3 has a good chance of making a difference. Without enough information, we could tell you whether or not it will matter… but when we're just trying to guess what could be wrong, we don't know whether it's going to matter. So, it's easier for you to just tell us up front.

Comment: @fuchsgeist: Also, it's a lot simpler to use raw strings (`r'working\path\to\myProgram.conf'`) or forward slashes (`'working/path/to/myProgram.conf'`) than deal with escaping backslashes. But they all should have equivalent effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't actually have a file encoded as UTF-8 without BOM.

You can generate a file with that string encoded that way as follows:

```
u='''{ "paths": ["A:\\path\\to\\dir"],
  "anotherPath": "os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..')"
}'''
s=u.encode('utf-8')
with open('test.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

(Whether the `'b'` is necessary or not depends on whether you're on Python 2 or 3, and whether you're on Windows or Unix. But if it's not necessary, it's harmless.)

Now, if you run your code against that file, it works.

But you can compare the `test.json` file to your `working\\path\\to\\myProgram.conf` file and see what the difference is. (Most non-Windows systems come with command-line tools like `hexdump`; on Windows you may have to get a little fancier to spot the differences.)